# timer for shell startup script

Tags: shell, timer, countdowntimer, startupscript

I am instanciating a machine on the cloud with a startup shell script (on ubuntu) which basically download some config files and run a python script. I would like to include some kind of security on the startup script which should reboot the machine 10 minutes after the startupscript started, and which is totally independent from what the startupscript is executing.

What would be a very clean way to do so?

Comment: what do you mean by `include some kind of security on the startup script which should reboot the machine 10 minutes after the startupscript`. Sorry, I didnt understand how both are related.

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab I want to reboot the machine 10 mins after startup script started, what ever it is doing.